# How to delete the word in front of the cursor in terminal on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal

I've read `fn + option + delete` will delete the word in front of cursor. This works for me in any of the editors i use, or any other text fields (chrome, textedit etc). However in terminal, the key combination just outputs a single `(`. I have no problem deleting a word behind the cursor with Option + delete.

I have seen I can map a key combination to an action in terminal preferences, but I haven't been able to find much documentation on the these actions.

The desired effect can be achieved by pressing `alt + d`, but i would like to use the `fn + option + delete` key combination. A possible sub-question would be how do I map `fn + option + delete` to `alt + d` in the terminal preferences?

Comment: It depends on the shell you use. In bash and other readline-aware programs for example you can use Alt-d.

Comment: i realised after writing the question that this is an option. I have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It's also the VISUAL setting (emacs mode vs. vi mode)

Comment: You can map option-forward delete to `\033d` which should simulate alt+d. Have to copy paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you're looking for as it will affect the whole line, but these are pretty handy.

To delete everything on a line before or after your cursor:

```
ctrl + w delete everything before the cursor
ctrl + k delete everything after the cursor
```